# Unable to get CPU and Memory Stats in perfmon Non Gui mode

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, perfmon

I am facing issue in getting CPU and Memory Usage statistics when I am browsing result file .jtl of the executed run.

Comment: What issues are you facing? Please share the details.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Non-GUI Mode](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/#Non-GUI-Mode) chapter of the [PerfMon Metrics Collector](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) documentation:

> If you run JMeter in non GUI mode and want to save monitoring data to file, **just configure result file saving in GUI** as you do with other listeners. After running the test you may load saved file into GUI and see the values timeline.

So just provide desired PerfMon results file location in the "Filename" input field of the "Write results to file" section

[image: JMeter PerfMon Results File Location]

And once your test is finished you will be able to load generated file into PerfMon Metrics Collector listener and see the charts.

Don't forget to start [Server Agent](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMonAgent/) process on the host which you would like to monitor and make sure default port 4444 is open for TCP and/or UDP transport.

More information on PerfMon installation, configuration and usage: [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)